# Initially hide toggle div

Tags: javascript, toggle, hide, show

I am trying to initially hide MyDiv. Then it is revealed on the click with toggle functions. However, I cannot initially hide it.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

This is my DIV element.

```
<script>function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the HTML for your div? Ideally, you should be able to `<div style='display:none'></div>` to hide the element on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works!

```js
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
function myFunction() {
    if (x.style.display === 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#myDIV{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div id="myDIV">Hello world!</div>
```

Or you could do this (not much of a difference):

```js
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
function myFunction() {
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div id="myDIV" style='display: none'>Hello world!</div>
```

**EDIT :**

This way you can send the `div`'s ID to the function:

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV')">Click me</button>
<div id="myDIV" style='display: none'>Hello world!</div>

<br />

<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV2')">Click me</button>
<div id="myDIV2" style='display: none'>Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: This helped. How about multiple onclick="myFunction() with a single html page? How do I set a unique ID for myFunction so I can use your example several times on 1 html page?

Comment: @SolomonBanbury edited my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better way:

**CSS**

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
<div id="my_div" class="hide"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('my_div');
    myDiv.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

Comment: This helped. How about multiple onclick="myFunction() with a single html page? How do I set a unique ID for myFunction so I can use your example several times on 1 html page?

Comment: add an ID param to the function, JS: function myFunction(id){ ...getElementById(id); ...}, HTML: <button onbClick="myFunction('my_div')" ...>

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS to hide it initially

```
<div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">Some DIV content</div>
```

Comment: This helped. How about multiple onclick="myFunction() with a single html page? How do I set a unique ID for myFunction so I can use your example several times on 1 html page?